# Cannot build Vue app when adding webpack extension

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, frontend

I'm trying to add this webpack extension and build my Vue app. From what I've read Vue/cli has webpack, and I've tried installing different versions of webpack too. For some reason I can't get Vue app to build. Anyone got a fix or can point out where I've gone wrong?

I've already tried removing/reinstalled node_modules and package-lock.json and all that.

Error when using `npm run build`

[image: Error when using npm run build]

Plugin add code

[image: Plugin add code]

package.json

[image: package.json]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`webpack-assets-manifest` 5.x is only compatible with Webpack 5, but you're using Vue CLI 4, which uses Webpack 4.

Either upgrade Vue CLI to 5.x:

```
npm i -D @vue/cli@5
```

or downgrade the plugin to 4.x:

```
npm i -D webpack-assets-manifest@4
```